# How to specify syntax error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller is like this

```
def show
    @receipt = Receipt.find(params[:id])
    @hospitalizations=@receipt.hospitalizations
    @outpatients=@receipt.outpatients
    @surgeries=@receipt.surgeries
  end
```

my show.html.erb is like this.

```
<h1>details of receiptid: <%= @receipt.id %></h1>

  <% @hospitalizations.each do |hospitalization| %>
  <p>hospitalization_id:<%= hospitalization.id %>hospitalization_start :<%= hospitalization.hospitalization_start %> hospitalization_end:<%= hospitalization.hospitalization_end %> </p>

  <% @surgeries.each do |surgery| %>
  <p>surgeryid:<%= surgery.id %> surgery_day :<%= surgery.surgery_day %>  </p>

 <% @outpatients.each do |outpatient| %>
  <p>outpatientid:<%=  outpatient.id %>outpatient_day :<%= outpatient.outpatient_day %> </p>

<% end %>
```

When I access it's page,some error like below was incurred. I tried to specify error location,but didn't work well.
It seems syntax error,where should end insert?
If someone has experienced same issues,please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your `each` loop requires an `<% end %>` clause, you can't find the specific line since the error says it reached the end when it expected "end". Close all your loops like this:

```
<% @hospitalizations.each do |hospitalization| %>
  <p>hospitalization_id:<%= hospitalization.id %>hospitalization_start :<%= hospitalization.hospitalization_start %> hospitalization_end:<%= hospitalization.hospitalization_end %> </p>
<% end %>
```